# Prevent specific .vue components from being bundled

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

**Problem**: In my `vue-cli 4` app, I'd like to have `build:` script, which generates production bundle, with specific `.vue-components` not being included in some cases. In other cases they should be included. Also, these components are stored in app itself - not in external library.

**I've tried**: to import `.vue-components` dynamically - let's say I have an array:

```
const customPreset = ['WidgetFirst', 'WidgetSecond', ...]
```

And empty object:

```
const widgets = {}
```

So I've tried to make something like this:

```
customPreset.forEach(v => { Object.assign(widgets, { [v]: () => import('./' + v + '.vue') }) })
export default widgets
```

Changing `customPreset` to some other array would allow to import another set of components...

But that doesn't work, because `import()` cannot operate with expressions.

So, what could be done to include various `.vue-components` into production bundle in various cases? Maybe it could be achieved through tweaking `vue.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `lazy loaded components`. In Vue they are available at multiple points.

1. In [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk) - you can import components per route, to load only when they are needed:

> This is how to define an async component that will be automatically code-split by webpack:

```js
const Foo = () => import('./Foo.vue')
```

You can also **group components in the same chunk**:

```js
const Foo = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ './Foo.vue')
const Bar = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ './Bar.vue')
const Baz = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ './Baz.vue')
```

2. Second option is [Dynamic/Async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html), which can be used in .vue files like this:

```js
Vue.component(
  'async-webpack-example',
  // The `import` function returns a Promise.
  () => import('./my-async-component')
)
```

It even support loading state, straight from the box:

```js
const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  // The component to load (should be a Promise)
  component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I'm using 2nd option, as there's no router in project. On local development this approach works fine, but when I'm exploring my production bundle contents with webpackBundleAnalyzer (after npm run build) - i still see all components, including those, which were not supposed to be included. It even seems like webpack puts .vue component into production bundle if it comes across import declaration in src code.

Comment: Did you try to add /* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ in component as well?

Comment: I'm importing component like this: Widget: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Widget" */ './Widget.vue')
Even if i try to import it conditionally - it somehow gets iincluded into production bundle...

Comment: Well, you will see all components in a bundle analyzer, they are just not loaded together. But they exists in different files in bundles. Like chunk.0.js

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to completely exclude some .vue-components from production .js bundle. My app comes to various clients with various configurations: some clients need to have one combination of widgets (.vue-components), while other clients don't need to have some of these widgets in their app copy. Of course, I can manually delete specific widgets (chunks) from dist folder, but there should be a better way of customizing the app...

Comment: Got it, then probably you need to move towards different webpack configs..

Comment: I'm now digging into webpack IgnorePlugin and also thinking about modifying ./src folder somehow just before npm run build to prevent webpack from processing specific .vue-files